# Is the mathematical syntax correct here (Taylor-polynomial)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

> Say I'm supposed to create the $2^{nd}$ degree Taylor-polynomial of
>   $f(x) = \cos x$ at $x_{0} = 0$

**I'd like to know if the syntax is correct**, how I solved this little task.

We have defined the Taylor-polynomial like that:

$$(T_{n, x_{0}}f)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}f^{k}(x_{0})(x-x_{0})^{k}$$

$f^{0}(x) = \cos x$

$f^{1}(x) = -\sin x$

$f^{2}(x) = -\cos x$

$\Rightarrow$

$$(T_{2, 0}f)(x) = \frac{1}{0!}f^{0}(0)(x-0)^{0} + \frac{1}{1!}f^{1}(0)(x-0)^{1}+ \frac{1}{2!}f^{2}(0)(x-0)^{2}$$

$$(T_{2, 0}f)(x) = \frac{1}{1}1\cdot1 + \frac{1}{1}0x^{1} + \frac{1}{2}(-1)x^{2}$$

$$(T_{2, 0}f)(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^{2}$$

Please be as strict as possible, I don't want get minus for syntax in the exam because every single point is very important.

Comment: I would suggest the notation $f^{(k)}(x)$, rather than $f^k(x)$, to denote the $k$th derivative of $f$ at $x$. Note too that I corrected your MathJax for the trig function names ($\cos x$ instead of $cosx$, etc.).

Comment: Oh you are right about that, just realized the definition is even with brackets in our script, thank you!
Any other mistakes?

Comment: If you want me to be as strict as possible, I would add $\forall x\in\mathbb R$ at some places.

Comment: I would use $1\cdot 1$, or $1(1)$, instead of $1*1$. Asterisks are only used in programming to denote multiplication, not in normal mathematical notation.

Comment: How did you do the dot? :D

Comment: "\cdot" produces the centered dot

Comment: Thank you that's very good to know, also it looks way better than star.

Comment: In displayed math mode, you can use \tfrac instead of \frac to force fractions to be smaller (if desired). That's a matter of taste. For example: $$\frac12 x^2\textrm{ versus } \tfrac 12 x^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is mostly correct. The only improvement I see is to write the $k$-th derivative as $f^{(k)}$, not $f^k$. This also applies when $k$ is a known number.

There is an alternative notation with apostrophes. So you should write $f^{(0)}(x)$ or $f(x)$, $f^{(1)}(x)$ or $f'(x)$, $f^{(2)}(x)$ or $f''(x)$ and so forth. The second one is generally only used for the first few derivatives. I've seen up to three apostrophes.